# How does SQL CE handles DB locks?

Tags: sql-server-ce

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/11/vs-2010-sp1-and-sql-ce.aspx

Have just read the article and still not clear on how SQLCe handles the DB locks.
Is it the same as SQLite does (blocks whole DB on writes so even reads get hanged) or it has some distinct mechanics?